# When the resolve callback from one promise returns another promise, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

At work, we are using a code structure over and over.  We all agree that it does work, but we don't know why it works.  This makes me uncomfortable.

I have made a fiddle that shows a simplified version of the code structure.  It runs.  Can anyone tell me what's going on?

http://jsfiddle.net/rhedin/zLbusowf/

Thanks.

I guess the url wasn't working.  I've changed it, but also here is the code:

```
function promiseAfter(seconds) {
  var promise = new Promise( (resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function () {resolve()}, 1000 * seconds)
  })
  return promise;
}

function dog() {
  console.log('Dog has started')
  cat().then(function () {
    console.log('In Dog. Cat has finished')
  })
  console.log('Dog has finished')
}

function cat() {
  console.log('Cat has started')
  return promiseAfter(1).then( () => {
    console.log('In Cat.  Outer promise satisfied')
    return promiseAfter(1).then( () => {
      console.log('In Cat.  Inner promise satisfied')
    })
  })
  console.log('Anything after the return stmt in Cat is never executed')
}

dog();
```

Comment: nope, because there's no code

Comment: Your jsfiddle link is broken. Why not paste the code into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens in your code is:

dog() calls cat(), cat call promise promiseAfter(1), promiseAfter(1) returns a Promise that will be resolved after 1 second, after this 1 second has passed and the promise has been resolved the second promiseAfter(1) of "cat" will be called (the most inner one), again this new promiseAfter(1) will be resolved after 1 second and then  "cat().then" inside the "dog" fn will be triggered, finishing the calls.

How does it work?

The "cat" function returns a promise generated by the first call to "promiseAfter(1)", this promise is chained with an inner promise returned by the inner "promiseAfter(1)". So cat will only be resolved, and call "then" of "cat().then" when the first "promiseAfter(1)" is resolved, and the first "promiseAfter(1)" will only be resolved after it's inner "promiseAfter(1)" is resolved.

Promises and promise chain:

I see that you are having problem with nested promises so I will try to explain in a little more detail.

Just to enforce the concept, a promise is an object "that represents an operation that hasn't completed yet, but is expected in the future" (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), this object has a method called "then", then is only triggered when your promise object is resolved, so

```
var promise = new Promise( (resolve) => {
    setTimeout(function () {resolve()}, 1000 * seconds)
})

// below the anonymous function passed to ".then" will only be called after 1 second (after the timeout is triggered and resolve() is called)
promise.then(function() { ... })
```

Now, returning to your code:

```
function cat() {
  return promiseAfter(1).then( () => { // will be resolved and call this anonymous function after 1 second
    console.log('In Cat.  Outer promise satisfied')
    return promiseAfter(1).then( () => { // will be resolved and call this anonymous function after the outer promise is resolved (1 second) and after 1 second has passed, so this will be called after 2 seconds
      console.log('In Cat.  Inner promise satisfied')
    })
  })
};
```

You already know that promiseAfter(1) will give you a promise, and that this promise will be resolved after 1 second. The thing is, the outer promiseAfter(1) calls its "then" method **passing an anonymous function that returns another promiseAfter(1)**, this is crucial to what's happening here, the fact that you return a new promise object inside the anonymous function passed to the .then method of the outer promiseAfter(1) **makes it adopt the eventual state of the inner promiseAfter(1)**. So in the end "cat()" will give you a promise object that will only be resolved when the innermost "promiseAfter(1)" is resolved, and the inner will only be resolved after the outer is resolved (1 second) and after 1 more second passes (1 to resolve the outer, plus 1 for the setTimeout of the inner to complete).`enter code here`

Comment: Hmm.  Well, I'm not sure I get it.  Let me try to show the events in order.  
  
1. Dog is called.  
2. Dog calls cat.  
3. Cat calls promiseAfter.  
4. PromiseAfter returns a promise, let's call it promise1.  
5. Cat attaches a callback to promise1, and returns it to dog.  
6. Dog attaches a callback to promise1, and exits.  
7. Promise1 resolves.

Comment: 8. Cat's callback on promise1 executes first, because it was queued first.
  Let's call cat's callback on promise1 callback1.
9. Callback1 calls promiseAfter.
10. PromiseAfter returns a promise, let's call it promise2.
11. Callback1 attaches a callback to promise2, and returns it to . . . 
  (I think this is where I lose it.  You can return a promise, as well 
  as a value, but I don't know what that means.)

Comment: I think I found the relevant part of the mdn documentation.  (But I don't really understand it.)  **Promise.resolve(value)** Returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value. _If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a then method), the returned promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state;_ otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value. Generally, if you want to know if a value is a promise or not - **Promise.resolve(value)** it instead and work with the return value as a promise.

Comment: I added a more detailed explation, hope it makes thing clear for you. Regarding your comment of the "Promise.resolve(value)", a more complete explanation would be that "Promise.resolve(value)" accepts a value or another object that has a "then" method (a thenable). If it's a value, then you have a promise that will immediatally call function passed to it's .then method, and pass "value" to then.

Comment: If it's a thenable (a promise as a .then method so it's a .thenable, thus you can pass a promise as a value to "Promise.resolve(value)") the resulting promise will only trigger it's .then method after the thenabled is resolved.

Comment: Bruno, I find the language here clearer:  https://promisesaplus.com/  _2.3. The Promise Resolution Procedure_ section.  But I'll accept your answer.  Thanks for your help.  &&  I'd like to understand what the designers of promises were intending to accomplish.  Is the "approved" way of serializing things this "return a promise within the callback" procedure?

Comment: Sorry if the explanation was a little clunky, I have some problems with explaining things in english ;(
The main objective of promises is to provide a more abstract way to deal with asynchronous code, it avoid you to fall in traps like [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). It's really hard at the beginning, but once you get it you will appreciate the beauty of it.